# Trying to Configuring AEM Assets integration with Marketing Cloud and Creative Cloud

Tags: aem

Trying to Configuring AEM Assets integration with Marketing Cloud and Creative Cloud by following [this Adobe documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/integration/configure-assets-cc-integration.html).
After configuring, I am trying to test the connection but connection failed.

```
http://{application-name}.marketing.adobe.com/bin/receive?sling:authRequestLogin=1
07.04.2017 06:17:04 - * HTTP Version: 1.1
07.04.2017 06:17:04 - * Using OAuth 2.0 Authorization Grants
07.04.2017 06:17:04 - * OAuth 2.0 User: Agent user ID
07.04.2017 06:17:04 - Failed to get an access token for user: Agent user ID msg: failed to get access token from authorization server status: 400 response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid issuer (iss) or subject (sub) provided"}
```

Anyone has faced this issue!!

Comment: That's normally because of invalid user credentials/name or the user account exists and does not have sufficient permissions. Check the account on MC.

Comment: I have already checked the MC configurations.Can you give me more directions?